# Console_init Causes Kernel paniC

Tags: linux, embedded, console, debian, arm

System Details:

OS: Debian/5.0 kernel 2.6.26-2 i686 SMP

Hardware: IBM Thinkpad T40 Type 2373 Pentium M 1.5GHz, 512MB RAM

Sources: sudo apt-get install linux-source-2.6.18 linux-patch-debian-2.6.18 linux-support-2.6.18-5

Toolchain: arm-linux-gcc3.4.cs-uclibc0.9.27 as installed by scratchbox

arm-linux-uclibc-gcc/-g++ -v:

```
Reading specs from /scratchbox/compilers/arm-linux-gcc3.4.cs-uclibc0.9.27/lib/gcc/arm-linux-uclibc/3.4.2/specs
Configured with: /home/larimo/sb-toolchains/cc/gcc-jp-pass2/work/gcc-2004-q3d/configure --target=arm-linux-uclibc   --host=i686-pc-linux-gnu --build=i686-pc-linux-gnu --prefix=/scratchbox/compilers/arm-linux-gcc3.4.cs-uclibc0.9.27 --enable-languages=c,c++ --program-prefix=arm-linux-uclibc- --enable-shared --enable-static --with-sysroot=/scratchbox/compilers/arm-linux-gcc3.4.cs-uclibc0.9.27 --with-local-prefix=/scratchbox/compilers/arm-linux-gcc3.4.cs-uclibc0.9.27 --enable-symvers=gnu --with-gnu-ld  Thread model: posix gcc version 3.4.2 (release) (CodeSourcery ARM Q3D 2004)
```

qemu-system-arm: v0.9.1

qemu command line: qemu-system-arm -m 32 -M integratorcp -kernel zImage -serial stdio -S -s

gdb command line: arm-uclibc-gdb --command=gdb_commands.vim --symbols /usr/src/linux-source-2.6.18/vmlinux

kernel config:

```
#
# Automatically generated make config: don't edit
# Linux kernel version: 2.6.18
# Mon Jun 22 14:52:14 2009
#
CONFIG_ARM=y
# CONFIG_GENERIC_TIME is not set
CONFIG_MMU=y
CONFIG_GENERIC_HARDIRQS=y
CONFIG_HARDIRQS_SW_RESEND=y
CONFIG_GENERIC_IRQ_PROBE=y
CONFIG_RWSEM_GENERIC_SPINLOCK=y
CONFIG_GENERIC_HWEIGHT=y
CONFIG_GENERIC_CALIBRATE_DELAY=y
CONFIG_VECTORS_BASE=0xffff0000
CONFIG_DEFCONFIG_LIST="/lib/modules/$UNAME_RELEASE/.config"

#
# Code maturity level options
#
CONFIG_EXPERIMENTAL=y
CONFIG_BROKEN_ON_SMP=y
CONFIG_LOCK_KERNEL=y
CONFIG_INIT_ENV_ARG_LIMIT=32

#
# General setup
#
CONFIG_LOCALVERSION=""
CONFIG_LOCALVERSION_AUTO=y
CONFIG_SWAP=y
CONFIG_SYSVIPC=y
# CONFIG_POSIX_MQUEUE is not set
# CONFIG_BSD_PROCESS_ACCT is not set
# CONFIG_TASKSTATS is not set
# CONFIG_AUDIT is not set
CONFIG_IKCONFIG=y
# CONFIG_IKCONFIG_PROC is not set
# CONFIG_RELAY is not set
CONFIG_INITRAMFS_SOURCE=""
# CONFIG_CC_OPTIMIZE_FOR_SIZE is not set
CONFIG_EMBEDDED=y
CONFIG_UID16=y
CONFIG_SYSCTL=y
CONFIG_KALLSYMS=y
CONFIG_KALLSYMS_ALL=y
# CONFIG_KALLSYMS_EXTRA_PASS is not set
# CONFIG_HOTPLUG is not set
CONFIG_PRINTK=y
CONFIG_BUG=y
CONFIG_ELF_CORE=y
CONFIG_BASE_FULL=y
# CONFIG_FUTEX is not set
CONFIG_EPOLL=y
# CONFIG_SHMEM is not set
# CONFIG_SLAB is not set
# CONFIG_VM_EVENT_COUNTERS is not set
CONFIG_TINY_SHMEM=y
CONFIG_BASE_SMALL=0
CONFIG_SLOB=y

#
# Loadable module support
#
CONFIG_MODULES=y
CONFIG_MODULE_UNLOAD=y
# CONFIG_MODULE_FORCE_UNLOAD is not set
# CONFIG_MODVERSIONS is not set
# CONFIG_MODULE_SRCVERSION_ALL is not set
CONFIG_KMOD=y

#
# Block layer
#
# CONFIG_BLK_DEV_IO_TRACE is not set

#
# IO Schedulers
#
CONFIG_IOSCHED_NOOP=y
CONFIG_IOSCHED_AS=y
CONFIG_IOSCHED_DEADLINE=y
CONFIG_IOSCHED_CFQ=y
# CONFIG_DEFAULT_AS is not set
# CONFIG_DEFAULT_DEADLINE is not set
CONFIG_DEFAULT_CFQ=y
# CONFIG_DEFAULT_NOOP is not set
CONFIG_DEFAULT_IOSCHED="cfq"

#
# System Type
#
# CONFIG_ARCH_AAEC2000 is not set
CONFIG_ARCH_INTEGRATOR=y
# CONFIG_ARCH_REALVIEW is not set
# CONFIG_ARCH_VERSATILE is not set
# CONFIG_ARCH_AT91 is not set
# CONFIG_ARCH_CLPS7500 is not set
# CONFIG_ARCH_CLPS711X is not set
# CONFIG_ARCH_CO285 is not set
# CONFIG_ARCH_EBSA110 is not set
# CONFIG_ARCH_EP93XX is not set
# CONFIG_ARCH_FOOTBRIDGE is not set
# CONFIG_ARCH_NETX is not set
# CONFIG_ARCH_H720X is not set
# CONFIG_ARCH_IMX is not set
# CONFIG_ARCH_IOP3XX is not set
# CONFIG_ARCH_IXP4XX is not set
# CONFIG_ARCH_IXP2000 is not set
# CONFIG_ARCH_IXP23XX is not set
# CONFIG_ARCH_L7200 is not set
# CONFIG_ARCH_PNX4008 is not set
# CONFIG_ARCH_PXA is not set
# CONFIG_ARCH_RPC is not set
# CONFIG_ARCH_SA1100 is not set
# CONFIG_ARCH_S3C2410 is not set
# CONFIG_ARCH_SHARK is not set
# CONFIG_ARCH_LH7A40X is not set
# CONFIG_ARCH_OMAP is not set

#
# Integrator Options
#
# CONFIG_ARCH_INTEGRATOR_AP is not set
CONFIG_ARCH_INTEGRATOR_CP=y
CONFIG_ARCH_CINTEGRATOR=y

#
# Processor Type
#
CONFIG_CPU_32=y
# CONFIG_CPU_ARM720T is not set
CONFIG_CPU_ARM920T=y
# CONFIG_CPU_ARM922T is not set
CONFIG_CPU_ARM926T=y
# CONFIG_CPU_ARM1020 is not set
# CONFIG_CPU_ARM1022 is not set
# CONFIG_CPU_ARM1026 is not set
# CONFIG_CPU_V6 is not set
CONFIG_CPU_32v4T=y
CONFIG_CPU_32v5=y
CONFIG_CPU_ABRT_EV4T=y
CONFIG_CPU_ABRT_EV5TJ=y
CONFIG_CPU_CACHE_V4WT=y
CONFIG_CPU_CACHE_VIVT=y
CONFIG_CPU_COPY_V4WB=y
CONFIG_CPU_TLB_V4WBI=y

#
# Processor Features
#
CONFIG_ARM_THUMB=y
# CONFIG_CPU_ICACHE_DISABLE is not set
# CONFIG_CPU_DCACHE_DISABLE is not set
# CONFIG_CPU_DCACHE_WRITETHROUGH is not set
# CONFIG_CPU_CACHE_ROUND_ROBIN is not set
CONFIG_ICST525=y

#
# Bus support
#
CONFIG_ARM_AMBA=y

#
# PCCARD (PCMCIA/CardBus) support
#

#
# Kernel Features
#
CONFIG_PREEMPT=y
# CONFIG_NO_IDLE_HZ is not set
CONFIG_HZ=100
# CONFIG_AEABI is not set
# CONFIG_ARCH_DISCONTIGMEM_ENABLE is not set
CONFIG_SELECT_MEMORY_MODEL=y
CONFIG_FLATMEM_MANUAL=y
# CONFIG_DISCONTIGMEM_MANUAL is not set
# CONFIG_SPARSEMEM_MANUAL is not set
CONFIG_FLATMEM=y
CONFIG_FLAT_NODE_MEM_MAP=y
# CONFIG_SPARSEMEM_STATIC is not set
CONFIG_SPLIT_PTLOCK_CPUS=4096
# CONFIG_RESOURCES_64BIT is not set
CONFIG_LEDS=y
CONFIG_LEDS_TIMER=y
CONFIG_LEDS_CPU=y
CONFIG_ALIGNMENT_TRAP=y

#
# Boot options
#
CONFIG_ZBOOT_ROM_TEXT=0x0
CONFIG_ZBOOT_ROM_BSS=0x0
CONFIG_CMDLINE="root=/dev/mtdblock2 mem=32M"
# CONFIG_XIP_KERNEL is not set

#
# CPU Frequency scaling
#
# CONFIG_CPU_FREQ is not set

#
# Floating point emulation
#

#
# At least one emulation must be selected
#
CONFIG_FPE_NWFPE=y
# CONFIG_FPE_NWFPE_XP is not set
# CONFIG_FPE_FASTFPE is not set
# CONFIG_VFP is not set

#
# Userspace binary formats
#
CONFIG_BINFMT_ELF=y
# CONFIG_BINFMT_AOUT is not set
# CONFIG_BINFMT_MISC is not set
# CONFIG_ARTHUR is not set

#
# Power management options
#
# CONFIG_PM is not set
# CONFIG_APM is not set

#
# Networking
#
CONFIG_NET=y

#
# Networking options
#
# CONFIG_NETDEBUG is not set
# CONFIG_PACKET is not set
CONFIG_UNIX=y
CONFIG_XFRM=y
# CONFIG_XFRM_USER is not set
# CONFIG_NET_KEY is not set
CONFIG_INET=y
# CONFIG_IP_MULTICAST is not set
# CONFIG_IP_ADVANCED_ROUTER is not set
CONFIG_IP_FIB_HASH=y
CONFIG_IP_PNP=y
CONFIG_IP_PNP_DHCP=y
# CONFIG_IP_PNP_BOOTP is not set
# CONFIG_IP_PNP_RARP is not set
# CONFIG_NET_IPIP is not set
# CONFIG_NET_IPGRE is not set
# CONFIG_ARPD is not set
# CONFIG_SYN_COOKIES is not set
# CONFIG_INET_AH is not set
# CONFIG_INET_ESP is not set
# CONFIG_INET_IPCOMP is not set
# CONFIG_INET_XFRM_TUNNEL is not set
# CONFIG_INET_TUNNEL is not set
CONFIG_INET_XFRM_MODE_TRANSPORT=y
CONFIG_INET_XFRM_MODE_TUNNEL=y
CONFIG_INET_DIAG=y
CONFIG_INET_TCP_DIAG=y
# CONFIG_TCP_CONG_ADVANCED is not set
CONFIG_TCP_CONG_BIC=y
# CONFIG_IPV6 is not set
# CONFIG_INET6_XFRM_TUNNEL is not set
# CONFIG_INET6_TUNNEL is not set
# CONFIG_NETWORK_SECMARK is not set
# CONFIG_NETFILTER is not set

#
# DCCP Configuration (EXPERIMENTAL)
#
# CONFIG_IP_DCCP is not set

#
# SCTP Configuration (EXPERIMENTAL)
#
# CONFIG_IP_SCTP is not set

#
# TIPC Configuration (EXPERIMENTAL)
#
# CONFIG_TIPC is not set
# CONFIG_ATM is not set
# CONFIG_BRIDGE is not set
# CONFIG_VLAN_8021Q is not set
# CONFIG_DECNET is not set
# CONFIG_LLC2 is not set
# CONFIG_IPX is not set
# CONFIG_ATALK is not set
# CONFIG_X25 is not set
# CONFIG_LAPB is not set
# CONFIG_ECONET is not set
# CONFIG_WAN_ROUTER is not set

#
# QoS and/or fair queueing
#
# CONFIG_NET_SCHED is not set

#
# Network testing
#
# CONFIG_NET_PKTGEN is not set
# CONFIG_HAMRADIO is not set
# CONFIG_IRDA is not set
# CONFIG_BT is not set
# CONFIG_IEEE80211 is not set

#
# Device Drivers
#

#
# Generic Driver Options
#
CONFIG_STANDALONE=y
CONFIG_PREVENT_FIRMWARE_BUILD=y
# CONFIG_DEBUG_DRIVER is not set
# CONFIG_SYS_HYPERVISOR is not set

#
# Connector - unified userspace <-> kernelspace linker
#
# CONFIG_CONNECTOR is not set

#
# Memory Technology Devices (MTD)
#
CONFIG_MTD=y
CONFIG_MTD_DEBUG=y
CONFIG_MTD_DEBUG_VERBOSE=2
CONFIG_MTD_CONCAT=y
CONFIG_MTD_PARTITIONS=y
CONFIG_MTD_REDBOOT_PARTS=y
CONFIG_MTD_REDBOOT_DIRECTORY_BLOCK=-1
# CONFIG_MTD_REDBOOT_PARTS_UNALLOCATED is not set
# CONFIG_MTD_REDBOOT_PARTS_READONLY is not set
CONFIG_MTD_CMDLINE_PARTS=y
# CONFIG_MTD_AFS_PARTS is not set

#
# User Modules And Translation Layers
#
CONFIG_MTD_CHAR=y
CONFIG_MTD_BLOCK=y
CONFIG_FTL=y
CONFIG_NFTL=y
# CONFIG_NFTL_RW is not set
CONFIG_INFTL=y
CONFIG_RFD_FTL=y

#
# RAM/ROM/Flash chip drivers
#
CONFIG_MTD_CFI=y
# CONFIG_MTD_JEDECPROBE is not set
CONFIG_MTD_GEN_PROBE=y
CONFIG_MTD_CFI_ADV_OPTIONS=y
CONFIG_MTD_CFI_NOSWAP=y
# CONFIG_MTD_CFI_BE_BYTE_SWAP is not set
# CONFIG_MTD_CFI_LE_BYTE_SWAP is not set
CONFIG_MTD_CFI_GEOMETRY=y
# CONFIG_MTD_MAP_BANK_WIDTH_1 is not set
# CONFIG_MTD_MAP_BANK_WIDTH_2 is not set
CONFIG_MTD_MAP_BANK_WIDTH_4=y
# CONFIG_MTD_MAP_BANK_WIDTH_8 is not set
# CONFIG_MTD_MAP_BANK_WIDTH_16 is not set
# CONFIG_MTD_MAP_BANK_WIDTH_32 is not set
# CONFIG_MTD_CFI_I1 is not set
CONFIG_MTD_CFI_I2=y
# CONFIG_MTD_CFI_I4 is not set
# CONFIG_MTD_CFI_I8 is not set
# CONFIG_MTD_OTP is not set
CONFIG_MTD_CFI_INTELEXT=y
# CONFIG_MTD_CFI_AMDSTD is not set
# CONFIG_MTD_CFI_STAA is not set
CONFIG_MTD_CFI_UTIL=y
# CONFIG_MTD_RAM is not set
# CONFIG_MTD_ROM is not set
# CONFIG_MTD_ABSENT is not set
# CONFIG_MTD_OBSOLETE_CHIPS is not set

#
# Mapping drivers for chip access
#
# CONFIG_MTD_COMPLEX_MAPPINGS is not set
# CONFIG_MTD_PHYSMAP is not set
# CONFIG_MTD_ARM_INTEGRATOR is not set
# CONFIG_MTD_PLATRAM is not set

#
# Self-contained MTD device drivers
#
# CONFIG_MTD_SLRAM is not set
# CONFIG_MTD_PHRAM is not set
# CONFIG_MTD_MTDRAM is not set
# CONFIG_MTD_BLOCK2MTD is not set

#
# Disk-On-Chip Device Drivers
#
# CONFIG_MTD_DOC2000 is not set
# CONFIG_MTD_DOC2001 is not set
# CONFIG_MTD_DOC2001PLUS is not set

#
# NAND Flash Device Drivers
#
# CONFIG_MTD_NAND is not set

#
# OneNAND Flash Device Drivers
#
# CONFIG_MTD_ONENAND is not set

#
# Parallel port support
#
# CONFIG_PARPORT is not set

#
# Plug and Play support
#

#
# Block devices
#
# CONFIG_BLK_DEV_COW_COMMON is not set
CONFIG_BLK_DEV_LOOP=y
# CONFIG_BLK_DEV_CRYPTOLOOP is not set
# CONFIG_BLK_DEV_NBD is not set
CONFIG_BLK_DEV_RAM=y
CONFIG_BLK_DEV_RAM_COUNT=1
CONFIG_BLK_DEV_RAM_SIZE=4096
CONFIG_BLK_DEV_RAM_BLOCKSIZE=256
CONFIG_BLK_DEV_INITRD=y
# CONFIG_CDROM_PKTCDVD is not set
# CONFIG_ATA_OVER_ETH is not set

#
# SCSI device support
#
# CONFIG_RAID_ATTRS is not set
# CONFIG_SCSI is not set

#
# Multi-device support (RAID and LVM)
#
# CONFIG_MD is not set

#
# Fusion MPT device support
#
# CONFIG_FUSION is not set

#
# IEEE 1394 (FireWire) support
#

#
# I2O device support
#

#
# Network device support
#
CONFIG_NETDEVICES=y
# CONFIG_DUMMY is not set
# CONFIG_BONDING is not set
# CONFIG_EQUALIZER is not set
# CONFIG_TUN is not set

#
# PHY device support
#
# CONFIG_PHYLIB is not set

#
# Ethernet (10 or 100Mbit)
#
CONFIG_NET_ETHERNET=y
CONFIG_MII=y
CONFIG_SMC91X=y
# CONFIG_DM9000 is not set

#
# Ethernet (1000 Mbit)
#

#
# Ethernet (10000 Mbit)
#

#
# Token Ring devices
#

#
# Wireless LAN (non-hamradio)
#
# CONFIG_NET_RADIO is not set

#
# Wan interfaces
#
# CONFIG_WAN is not set
# CONFIG_PPP is not set
# CONFIG_SLIP is not set
# CONFIG_SHAPER is not set
# CONFIG_NETCONSOLE is not set
# CONFIG_NETPOLL is not set
# CONFIG_NET_POLL_CONTROLLER is not set

#
# ISDN subsystem
#
# CONFIG_ISDN is not set

#
# Input device support
#
CONFIG_INPUT=y

#
# Userland interfaces
#
CONFIG_INPUT_MOUSEDEV=y
CONFIG_INPUT_MOUSEDEV_PSAUX=y
CONFIG_INPUT_MOUSEDEV_SCREEN_X=1024
CONFIG_INPUT_MOUSEDEV_SCREEN_Y=768
# CONFIG_INPUT_JOYDEV is not set
# CONFIG_INPUT_TSDEV is not set
CONFIG_INPUT_EVDEV=y
# CONFIG_INPUT_EVBUG is not set

#
# Input Device Drivers
#
CONFIG_INPUT_KEYBOARD=y
CONFIG_KEYBOARD_ATKBD=y
# CONFIG_KEYBOARD_SUNKBD is not set
# CONFIG_KEYBOARD_LKKBD is not set
# CONFIG_KEYBOARD_XTKBD is not set
# CONFIG_KEYBOARD_NEWTON is not set
# CONFIG_INPUT_MOUSE is not set
# CONFIG_INPUT_JOYSTICK is not set
# CONFIG_INPUT_TOUCHSCREEN is not set
# CONFIG_INPUT_MISC is not set

#
# Hardware I/O ports
#
CONFIG_SERIO=y
# CONFIG_SERIO_SERPORT is not set
# CONFIG_SERIO_AMBAKMI is not set
CONFIG_SERIO_LIBPS2=y
# CONFIG_SERIO_RAW is not set
# CONFIG_GAMEPORT is not set

#
# Character devices
#
CONFIG_VT=y
CONFIG_VT_CONSOLE=y
CONFIG_HW_CONSOLE=y
CONFIG_VT_HW_CONSOLE_BINDING=y
# CONFIG_SERIAL_NONSTANDARD is not set

#
# Serial drivers
#
# CONFIG_SERIAL_8250 is not set

#
# Non-8250 serial port support
#
# CONFIG_SERIAL_AMBA_PL010 is not set
CONFIG_SERIAL_AMBA_PL011=y
CONFIG_SERIAL_AMBA_PL011_CONSOLE=y
CONFIG_SERIAL_CORE=y
CONFIG_SERIAL_CORE_CONSOLE=y
CONFIG_UNIX98_PTYS=y
CONFIG_LEGACY_PTYS=y
CONFIG_LEGACY_PTY_COUNT=256

#
# IPMI
#
# CONFIG_IPMI_HANDLER is not set

#
# Watchdog Cards
#
# CONFIG_WATCHDOG is not set
CONFIG_HW_RANDOM=y
# CONFIG_NVRAM is not set
# CONFIG_DTLK is not set
# CONFIG_R3964 is not set

#
# Ftape, the floppy tape device driver
#
# CONFIG_RAW_DRIVER is not set

#
# TPM devices
#
# CONFIG_TCG_TPM is not set
# CONFIG_TELCLOCK is not set

#
# I2C support
#
# CONFIG_I2C is not set

#
# SPI support
#
# CONFIG_SPI is not set
# CONFIG_SPI_MASTER is not set

#
# Dallas's 1-wire bus
#

#
# Hardware Monitoring support
#
CONFIG_HWMON=y
# CONFIG_HWMON_VID is not set
# CONFIG_SENSORS_ABITUGURU is not set
# CONFIG_SENSORS_F71805F is not set
# CONFIG_HWMON_DEBUG_CHIP is not set

#
# Misc devices
#

#
# LED devices
#
# CONFIG_NEW_LEDS is not set

#
# LED drivers
#

#
# LED Triggers
#

#
# Multimedia devices
#
# CONFIG_VIDEO_DEV is not set

#
# Digital Video Broadcasting Devices
#
# CONFIG_DVB is not set

#
# Graphics support
#
# CONFIG_FIRMWARE_EDID is not set
CONFIG_FB=y
CONFIG_FB_CFB_FILLRECT=y
CONFIG_FB_CFB_COPYAREA=y
CONFIG_FB_CFB_IMAGEBLIT=y
# CONFIG_FB_MACMODES is not set
# CONFIG_FB_BACKLIGHT is not set
CONFIG_FB_MODE_HELPERS=y
CONFIG_FB_TILEBLITTING=y
CONFIG_FB_ARMCLCD=y
CONFIG_FB_S1D13XXX=y
# CONFIG_FB_VIRTUAL is not set

#
# Console display driver support
#
CONFIG_VGA_CONSOLE=y
# CONFIG_VGACON_SOFT_SCROLLBACK is not set
CONFIG_DUMMY_CONSOLE=y
CONFIG_FRAMEBUFFER_CONSOLE=y
# CONFIG_FRAMEBUFFER_CONSOLE_ROTATION is not set
CONFIG_FONTS=y
CONFIG_FONT_8x8=y
CONFIG_FONT_8x16=y
# CONFIG_FONT_6x11 is not set
# CONFIG_FONT_7x14 is not set
CONFIG_FONT_PEARL_8x8=y
CONFIG_FONT_ACORN_8x8=y
CONFIG_FONT_MINI_4x6=y
CONFIG_FONT_SUN8x16=y
# CONFIG_FONT_SUN12x22 is not set
# CONFIG_FONT_10x18 is not set

#
# Logo configuration
#
CONFIG_LOGO=y
CONFIG_LOGO_LINUX_MONO=y
CONFIG_LOGO_LINUX_VGA16=y
CONFIG_LOGO_LINUX_CLUT224=y
# CONFIG_BACKLIGHT_LCD_SUPPORT is not set

#
# Sound
#
# CONFIG_SOUND is not set

#
# USB support
#
CONFIG_USB_ARCH_HAS_HCD=y
# CONFIG_USB_ARCH_HAS_OHCI is not set
# CONFIG_USB_ARCH_HAS_EHCI is not set
# CONFIG_USB is not set

#
# NOTE: USB_STORAGE enables SCSI, and 'SCSI disk support'
#

#
# USB Gadget Support
#
# CONFIG_USB_GADGET is not set

#
# MMC/SD Card support
#
# CONFIG_MMC is not set

#
# Real Time Clock
#
CONFIG_RTC_LIB=y
# CONFIG_RTC_CLASS is not set

#
# File systems
#
CONFIG_EXT2_FS=y
# CONFIG_EXT2_FS_XATTR is not set
# CONFIG_EXT2_FS_XIP is not set
# CONFIG_EXT3_FS is not set
# CONFIG_REISERFS_FS is not set
# CONFIG_JFS_FS is not set
# CONFIG_FS_POSIX_ACL is not set
# CONFIG_XFS_FS is not set
# CONFIG_OCFS2_FS is not set
# CONFIG_MINIX_FS is not set
CONFIG_ROMFS_FS=y
CONFIG_INOTIFY=y
CONFIG_INOTIFY_USER=y
# CONFIG_QUOTA is not set
CONFIG_DNOTIFY=y
# CONFIG_AUTOFS_FS is not set
# CONFIG_AUTOFS4_FS is not set
# CONFIG_FUSE_FS is not set

#
# CD-ROM/DVD Filesystems
#
# CONFIG_ISO9660_FS is not set
# CONFIG_UDF_FS is not set

#
# DOS/FAT/NT Filesystems
#
CONFIG_FAT_FS=y
CONFIG_MSDOS_FS=y
# CONFIG_VFAT_FS is not set
CONFIG_FAT_DEFAULT_CODEPAGE=437
# CONFIG_NTFS_FS is not set

#
# Pseudo filesystems
#
CONFIG_PROC_FS=y
CONFIG_SYSFS=y
# CONFIG_TMPFS is not set
# CONFIG_HUGETLB_PAGE is not set
CONFIG_RAMFS=y
# CONFIG_CONFIGFS_FS is not set

#
# Miscellaneous filesystems
#
# CONFIG_ADFS_FS is not set
# CONFIG_AFFS_FS is not set
# CONFIG_ASFS_FS is not set
# CONFIG_HFS_FS is not set
# CONFIG_HFSPLUS_FS is not set
# CONFIG_BEFS_FS is not set
# CONFIG_BFS_FS is not set
# CONFIG_EFS_FS is not set
# CONFIG_JFFS_FS is not set
CONFIG_JFFS2_FS=y
CONFIG_JFFS2_FS_DEBUG=0
CONFIG_JFFS2_FS_WRITEBUFFER=y
# CONFIG_JFFS2_SUMMARY is not set
# CONFIG_JFFS2_FS_XATTR is not set
# CONFIG_JFFS2_COMPRESSION_OPTIONS is not set
CONFIG_JFFS2_ZLIB=y
CONFIG_JFFS2_RTIME=y
# CONFIG_JFFS2_RUBIN is not set
CONFIG_CRAMFS=y
# CONFIG_VXFS_FS is not set
# CONFIG_HPFS_FS is not set
# CONFIG_QNX4FS_FS is not set
# CONFIG_SYSV_FS is not set
# CONFIG_UFS_FS is not set

#
# Network File Systems
#
CONFIG_NFS_FS=y
# CONFIG_NFS_V3 is not set
# CONFIG_NFS_V4 is not set
# CONFIG_NFS_DIRECTIO is not set
# CONFIG_NFSD is not set
CONFIG_ROOT_NFS=y
CONFIG_LOCKD=y
CONFIG_NFS_COMMON=y
CONFIG_SUNRPC=y
# CONFIG_RPCSEC_GSS_KRB5 is not set
# CONFIG_RPCSEC_GSS_SPKM3 is not set
# CONFIG_SMB_FS is not set
# CONFIG_CIFS is not set
# CONFIG_NCP_FS is not set
# CONFIG_CODA_FS is not set
# CONFIG_AFS_FS is not set
# CONFIG_9P_FS is not set

#
# Partition Types
#
# CONFIG_PARTITION_ADVANCED is not set
CONFIG_MSDOS_PARTITION=y

#
# Native Language Support
#
CONFIG_NLS=y
CONFIG_NLS_DEFAULT="iso8859-1"
# CONFIG_NLS_CODEPAGE_437 is not set
# CONFIG_NLS_CODEPAGE_737 is not set
# CONFIG_NLS_CODEPAGE_775 is not set
# CONFIG_NLS_CODEPAGE_850 is not set
# CONFIG_NLS_CODEPAGE_852 is not set
# CONFIG_NLS_CODEPAGE_855 is not set
# CONFIG_NLS_CODEPAGE_857 is not set
# CONFIG_NLS_CODEPAGE_860 is not set
# CONFIG_NLS_CODEPAGE_861 is not set
# CONFIG_NLS_CODEPAGE_862 is not set
# CONFIG_NLS_CODEPAGE_863 is not set
# CONFIG_NLS_CODEPAGE_864 is not set
# CONFIG_NLS_CODEPAGE_865 is not set
# CONFIG_NLS_CODEPAGE_866 is not set
# CONFIG_NLS_CODEPAGE_869 is not set
# CONFIG_NLS_CODEPAGE_936 is not set
# CONFIG_NLS_CODEPAGE_950 is not set
# CONFIG_NLS_CODEPAGE_932 is not set
# CONFIG_NLS_CODEPAGE_949 is not set
# CONFIG_NLS_CODEPAGE_874 is not set
# CONFIG_NLS_ISO8859_8 is not set
# CONFIG_NLS_CODEPAGE_1250 is not set
# CONFIG_NLS_CODEPAGE_1251 is not set
# CONFIG_NLS_ASCII is not set
CONFIG_NLS_ISO8859_1=y
# CONFIG_NLS_ISO8859_2 is not set
# CONFIG_NLS_ISO8859_3 is not set
# CONFIG_NLS_ISO8859_4 is not set
# CONFIG_NLS_ISO8859_5 is not set
# CONFIG_NLS_ISO8859_6 is not set
# CONFIG_NLS_ISO8859_7 is not set
# CONFIG_NLS_ISO8859_9 is not set
# CONFIG_NLS_ISO8859_13 is not set
# CONFIG_NLS_ISO8859_14 is not set
# CONFIG_NLS_ISO8859_15 is not set
# CONFIG_NLS_KOI8_R is not set
# CONFIG_NLS_KOI8_U is not set
# CONFIG_NLS_UTF8 is not set

#
# Profiling support
#
# CONFIG_PROFILING is not set

#
# Kernel hacking
#
CONFIG_PRINTK_TIME=y
CONFIG_MAGIC_SYSRQ=y
# CONFIG_UNUSED_SYMBOLS is not set
CONFIG_DEBUG_KERNEL=y
CONFIG_LOG_BUF_SHIFT=14
CONFIG_DETECT_SOFTLOCKUP=y
# CONFIG_SCHEDSTATS is not set
# CONFIG_DEBUG_SPINLOCK is not set
# CONFIG_DEBUG_MUTEXES is not set
# CONFIG_DEBUG_RWSEMS is not set
# CONFIG_DEBUG_SPINLOCK_SLEEP is not set
# CONFIG_DEBUG_LOCKING_API_SELFTESTS is not set
CONFIG_DEBUG_KOBJECT=y
CONFIG_DEBUG_BUGVERBOSE=y
CONFIG_DEBUG_INFO=y
# CONFIG_DEBUG_FS is not set
# CONFIG_DEBUG_VM is not set
CONFIG_FRAME_POINTER=y
CONFIG_UNWIND_INFO=y
CONFIG_FORCED_INLINING=y
# CONFIG_RCU_TORTURE_TEST is not set
CONFIG_DEBUG_USER=y
# CONFIG_DEBUG_WAITQ is not set
CONFIG_DEBUG_ERRORS=y
CONFIG_DEBUG_LL=y
# CONFIG_DEBUG_ICEDCC is not set

#
# Security options
#
# CONFIG_KEYS is not set
# CONFIG_SECURITY is not set

#
# Cryptographic options
#
# CONFIG_CRYPTO is not set

#
# Hardware crypto devices
#

#
# Library routines
#
# CONFIG_CRC_CCITT is not set
# CONFIG_CRC16 is not set
CONFIG_CRC32=y
# CONFIG_LIBCRC32C is not set
CONFIG_ZLIB_INFLATE=y
CONFIG_ZLIB_DEFLATE=y
```

> I am trying to run a cross-compiled kernel in qemu. I am trying to simulate an ARM9 family processor on an integratorcp board.  This is supported under qemu-system-arm and this setting is present in the command line far above.  Although I am using the cross build toolchain supplied by scratchbox I am not compiling in scratchbox.  This is because cross support is quite well developed for the kernel and is actually recommended to *not* be done in scratchbox.  Everything is compiled into this kernel.  Although loadable module support is enabled no modules are being built.  I am able to succesfully produce a compressed binary (zImage).  When qemu-system-arm inserts it as the kernel it sucessfully uncompresses Linux and almost immediately hangs.  Feeding an uncompressed kernel binary (/usr/src/linux-2.8.16-source/vmlinux) to arm-uclibc-gdb for symbol extraction seems to work as well.  Setting breakpoints and stepping through the instructions seems accurate.  I was able to use arm-uclibc-gdb to trap the offending line.  The crash occurs in drivers/video/console/vgacon.c:462, inside the vgacon_startup(void) function.  After attempting to step into the instruction inb_p(VGA_IS1_RC) on line 462 it craps the bed.  Setting a breakpoint at __do_kernel_fault, the callstack is as follows:`

```
#0  __do_kernel_fault (mm=0xc0225f28, addr=53, fsr=53, regs=0x30001)
    at arch/arm/mm/fault.c:82
#1  0xc002a03c in do_bad_area (tsk=0xc0228340, mm=0xc0225e34, 
    addr=3221397564, fsr=53, regs=0xc0225f28) at arch/arm/mm/fault.c:145
#2  0xc002a2fc in do_translation_fault (addr=3223477848, fsr=53, 
    regs=0xc0225f28) at arch/arm/mm/fault.c:356
#3  0xc002a39c in do_DataAbort (addr=3992978394, fsr=53, 
    regs=0xc0225f28) at arch/arm/mm/fault.c:450
#4  0xc0023848 in __dabt_svc () at proc_fs.h:194
#5  0xc0023848 in __dabt_svc () at proc_fs.h:194
#6  0xc0023848 in __dabt_svc () at proc_fs.h:194
#7  0xc0023848 in __dabt_svc () at proc_fs.h:194
#8  0xc0023848 in __dabt_svc () at proc_fs.h:194
#9  0xc0023848 in __dabt_svc () at proc_fs.h:194
...
#1500  0xc0023848 in __dabt_svc () at proc_fs.h:194
...
#15000  0xc0023848 in __dabt_svc () at proc_fs.h:194
...
```

I eventually gave up trying to find what was calling `__dabt_svc`

A couple points of interest:

- It seems impossible to inspect and set breaks on certain variables/functions even when they are within scope (`inb_p`, for example).
- I have tried compiling with no optimization, -O and -O2 and have not succeeded in booting past this issue

  - The `inb_p`, man documentation clearly states that you need to compile with -O or -O2; otherwise, you risk the subroutine not being inlined
- Although it prints the "Uncompressing Linux.....Ok, Booting the kernel" message to the screen, once it starts initializing the console you are flying blind.  Nothing else gets printed to the screen by the kernel.  There is no pretty-print panic message - you have to break into `__show_regs()` and manually snoop all the relevant registers (pc, fsr, etc).  This is not as difficult as it sounds.  It is about as tedious as it sounds.
- I believe I have applied all relevant patches for ARM as well as for Debian.
- I am ready to cry like a little girl with a skinned knee.

I would be very grateful for a fresh pair of eyes, or at the very least a nod in the right direction.  Thank you in advance for having read this far and for any assistance you can provide.

Comment: I was forced to remove the top-level kernel makefile as it was taking up too much space.  The only changes to it were:
ARCH ?= arm
CROSS_COMPILE ?= /scratchbox/compilers/arm-linux-gcc3.4.cs-uclibc0.9.27/bin/arm-linux-uclibc-
HOSTCFLAGS   = -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -g
HOSTCXXFLAGS = -g

Answer (score 2):

It appears that QEMU does not emulate the VGA device in its Arm integrator emulation.

Check out [this link](http://909ers.apl.washington.edu/~dushaw/ARM/) for a possible workaround.

Comment: Yeah, I was wondering about that.  I hit that link before, it looks like they're using a different machine emulation (versatilepb).  I've been able to boot into that before.  But then I found a Chinese website which seems to imply that what I'm trying to do can be done.  I can't tell though because I can't read Chinese.

In case anyone's interested:
http://blog.chinaunix.net/u1/34715/showart_1269885.html

Answer (score 1):

What is the kernel command line ? You shoul first put the console on the serial port using
a line like this :

`console=/dev/ttyS0` or `console=/dev/ttyAMA0`

Then the messages should start to flow. If your kernel dies too early, you can also try the following hack :

```
Index: .kernel/kernel/printk.c
===================================================================
--- .kernel.orig/kernel/printk.c    2009-02-28 02:52:32.000000000 +0100
+++ .kernel/kernel/printk.c 2009-04-30 14:12:29.000000000 +0200
@@ -41,6 +41,7 @@
 {
 }

+extern void printascii(const char *);
 #define __LOG_BUF_LEN  (1 << CONFIG_LOG_BUF_SHIFT)

 /* printk's without a loglevel use this.. */
@@ -552,7 +553,7 @@

    /* Emit the output into the temporary buffer */
    printed_len = vscnprintf(printk_buf, sizeof(printk_buf), fmt, args);
-
+        printascii(printk_buf);
    if (printed_len > 0) {
        unsigned int loglevel;
        int mark_len;
```

Comment: Shodanex,

This is ON POINT.  Worked like a charm.  I was planning on doing something like this but had no idea how to approach it.  Is this your own?  If not, where did you discover it? How did you know this would work?  Where does printascii come from?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I have been working with various ARM processor on custom hardware, and if you did not get it right the first time, then you need at least some debugging help. serial console is a standard on ARM, and the printascii hack regularly show up on ARM linux mailing list when people are stuck with a silently failing kernel.